# Declare constructor of a derived class as friend of parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

As every C++ newbie out there I am coding my own matrix class as an exercise. I am using class templates like this:

```
template<typename T>
class BMatrix {
public:
    // Constructors
    BMatrix(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols);
    BMatrix(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols, T ival);
    BMatrix(const BMatrix<T>& a);
    // Destructor
    ~BMatrix();

    // Access
    T& operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col);
    T  operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col) const;

    // ...

    // Friends
    //friend BDiagonal<T>::BDiagonal(unsigned size, T val);

private:
    unsigned nrows_, ncols_;
    T* data_;
};
```

The constructor of BMatrix allocates an array data_ of size nrows_*ncols_.

Now, as you can see I want to declare the constructor of another class, BDiagonal, as a friend. The class BDiagonal is a derived class of BMatrix. The motivation behind this is that BDiagonal will save memory (I only need to store the n non-zero elements of an nxn diagonal matrix) and make some operations faster. So I want the constructor of this matrix to allocate an array data_ of size nrows*1, but still have nrows_ and ncols_ larger than 1. With this I could still use some functionalities that I have implemented for the BMatrix class (such as an overloaded << operator to print the matrix).

Rather unsurprisingly this did not compile, and instead the compiler throws the error:

```
BArray/core.h:86:9: error: ‘BDiagonal’ does not name a type
friend BDiagonal<T>::BDiagonal(unsigned size, T val);
```

If I forward declare BDiagonal at the beginning of the file I get:

```
BArray/core.h:546:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class BMatrix<double>’
 class BDiagonal : public BMatrix<T> {
       ^~~~~~~~~
BArray/core.h:55:7: note: declaration of ‘class BMatrix<double>’
 class BMatrix {
```

I've tried forward declaring BMatrix as well, but that leads to more errors. I don't want to declare the private members of BMatrix protected because that would lead to anyone being able to access them directly by deriving a class.

Is there a way to do this? And more importantly, are there any reasons why I should not do this and take a different approach for my BDIagonal class?

Cheers

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of `BDiagonal`.

Comment: it compile for me https://onlinegdb.com/HyDb--JiU

Comment: and also if you are writing in modern c++ have the rule of 5, not 3 you missed the move constructor and the  move assignment operator

Comment: Unless the assignment is about explicit dynamic memory handling, use a `std::vector` instead and follow the rule of *zero*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need something to be accessible in the derived class then make it protected instead of private. You don't need friend in this case.

You might also add a protected constructor in `BMatrix` that initializes `data_` with the desired number of elements that you could call (delegate) in your derived class constructor.

For instance, you could add the protected constructor below

```
BMatrix(std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> dimension, unsigned int numElements);
```

Then in BMatrix you would write

```cpp
BMatrix(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols) : BMatrix({nrows, ncols}, nrows * ncols) {}
```

and a possible constructor for `BDiagonal` could be

```cpp
BDiagonal(size) : BMatrix({size, size}, size) {}
```

With this `BDiagonal` would only allocate space for `size` elements instead of `size*size`.

---

Edit

I have changed the protected constructor to receive an `std::pair` for the dimension instead of two numbers to avoid ambiguity with the constructor that receives `T ival`, but there are other ways to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer. Now I have a different problem. I have 2 constructors for BMatrix. One takes two arguments (nrows, ncols), and I delegate it to the 3 args protected constructor, as in your example. Then I have a 3 args constructor (like the 2 args plus an initial value to fill the matrix with), and I delegate it to another protected constructor that takes 4 args. When I declare BMatrix a(1,2,3) from main(), the compiler says the call is ambiguous bc there are 2 candidates that take 3 args. But one of them is protected, so I wouldn't expect that I can call it from main.

Comment: For example, if I try BMatrix a(1,2,3,4) from main, the compiler will say it is protected.

Comment: (By now I think declaring the private members of BMatrix protected is probably the simplest solution, I just want to deepen my understanding of the problem).

Comment: Oh, I see, the protected constructor I have suggested might clash with the constructor that received an initial value. There are multiple ways to solve this. I have update the answer with one possible way.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is the solution I came up with in the meantime, except I set the first argument of the protected constructors as a std::string containing the matrix type, which I can then use when calling the overloaded << operator. So BMatrix(1,2,3) delegates on BMatrix("BMatrix",1,2,1*2,3), and BDiagonal(3, 4) delegates on BMatrix("BDiagonal",3,3,3,4). Cheers!

Comment: That is even better. Each matrix has a "name" which is set by the derived class constructor and the `extra std::string` parameter in the protected constructor is enough to disambiguate.